# Fluid gets Stuck in the Middle of Pipe

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I am trying to simulate fluid running through an array of pipes into a destination tank. The fluid runs fine through my system until it reaches a bend in the pipe and then it just stops.
[image]
[image]
The pipes and joints are set as obstacles and the domain is more than large enough to encompass the whole system.

I tried scaling everything, deleting the inflows and re-inserting them, deleting the domain and re-inserting it, redrawing the place where the fluid is being stuck, changing fluid velocities, and nothing has helped.

Any help is appreciated. Also I am happy to send the file out for someone else to play with to see if I am missing something.

Comment: In cases like this first thing to check is non-manifold geometry (e.g. hidden faces inside those pipes), then fluid resolution as already mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try increasing the [fluid domain resolution](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/domain.html#options) or switching from "preview" to "final" in both Viewport and Render Display (in the Fluid Domain options).

It looks like the dimension of each fluid grid element is comparable to the section of the pipe, therefore a slight change to the pipe geometry can result in an obstruction for the fluid. Alternatively, you can make the pipe section larger.

If you're going to increase the resolution, do it little by little (around +20) or be aware that the simulation time and required memory can dramatically increase.