# Flow water from one Object to Another

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I'm fairly new to Blender but have done a fair few tutorials and starting to get my head around things.  I've recently watched a Tutorial on Water Physics and had no issues following along and have the water flowing in to an object and filling it up.

I've since tried adding another object below/offset to the first one and cut out a hole in the first object (with the hope that the water would flow in to Object A, through the Hole in Object A and start filling up Object B.  Unfortunately this isn't happening as I'd hoped (and I'm sure it's something I'm missing or doing wrong)[image: This is an image of what I've got so far to hopefully better show what I'm attempting]

If anyone could shed some light on where I'm going wrong or what I should be doing, that would be great.  After writing this, I've just had an idea of creating a secondary water flow from the hole(/pipe) and having that start flowing once the water from the first one gets to a set point (but would rather take the time to learn and do it properly than hack my way around)

Comment: Just a guess, but the original domain could be too small.

Comment: Sorry, should have said, I've changed the Domain size to ensure that it covers both objects.  The fluid will overflow with no issues, it just won't go through the hole I've cut out?!

Comment: Your hole could be too small, at least for the fluid resolution you are using. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80992/16395

Comment: @NicolaSap  I've tried making the hole really big and setting the Final Resolution to 200 before baking but it still does the same thing? I used Boolean to create the hole from a cylinder I had through the Object (was this the right thing to do, is this possibly why It's not working?

Comment: Have you "applied" the boolean modifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you made the hole through Boolean operations, you must Apply the modifiers before baking

[image]

**Boolean** not applied (still in the stack):

[image]

**Boolean applied** (no more in the stack):

[image]

I don't think it's possible, at the moment, to bring the *Boolean* modifier above *Fluidism*, or to *Use Modifier Stack* in the *Fluid Obstacle* settings

Comment: Thank you, I had applied it but it was still not going through.  I've tried again with a new Project and it's still not working?!  What Fluid settings do you have for the objects, just in case I'm missing something in the Fluid Settings.  I've got a Domain, and Inflow and a Obstacle (with the hole in it).  I'm more than happy to supply the Blend file if needs be so you can see what I've done and where I've gone wrong?

Comment: It's all good now.  I tried setting the resolution to 300 and it's going through now :) just takes a while to bake which sucks, but it's working now and that's the main thing :) thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Free the bake with the proper button and bake the simulation again, this time with Object A as an obstacle and the right domain size. Once it's baked, the sim sticks to the given params and any changes require re-baking.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, I'd tried rebaking but to no avail.  I've even tried making the hole really bit and setting the render of the fluid bake to 200 but it still does the same thing?  I used Boolean to create the hole from a cylinder I had through the Object (was this the right thing to do, is this possibly why It's not working?